# Unable to read memory from SDL_GetAudioDeviceName

Tags: c++, memory, sdl-2, unreal-engine4

I try to get the name of my audio device with SDL_GetAudioDeviceName and store it into a const char* variable.

The problem is that I just can't do:

```
cont char* RecorderName = SDL_GetAudioDeviceName()
```

When I run it into debug mode, my RecorderName variable is just = NULL instead of the adress that SDL_GetAudioDeviceName returns.

Do you know any solution for that?

[image]

Comment: `When I run it into debug mode, my RecorderName variable is just = NULL instead of the adress that SDL_GetAudioDeviceName returns.` I guess `SDL_GetAudioDeviceName` returns `NULL`, thats why it's `NULL`.

Comment: Hi, actually you can see on the capture that SDL_GetAudioDeviceName doesn't return NULL, there's an address here : `0x00007ffaca58269c`
I don't understand why that address is not passed to RecorderName when using the = operator

Comment: This is the address of the function itself, not what it returns.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that.
I've finally found where the problem came from. 
I was using RecorderIndex as parameter for GetAudioDeviceName. However, the RecorderIndex (here it was = 2) was not a valid index for GetAudioDeviceName. I fed it with 0 instead and it returned me the name.

The function GetAudioDevice returned 2 as a valid ID for the capture device, so I went on and set RecorderIndex to this value, but it seems that it's actually not a valid ID for GetAudioDeviceName.

I'm not sure to understand why though, if someone has an explanation I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: @MaximeParata `SDL_AudioDeviceID` returned by `SDL_OpenAudioDevice` is not an [0; num_devices) index suitable for `SDL_GetAudioDeviceName`. It is other way around - you're supposed to get number of devices and iterate over them, possibly asking user to choose one, and then use that name to open device. That is kind of problemmatic as there is currently no way to open audio device by index.

Comment: @keltar thanks for clarifying, although I don't understand how you can get it the other way around?
You can actually open you audio device by name?

Comment: @MaximeParata [SDL_OpenAudioDevice](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_OpenAudioDevice) first argument is a device name.